# are sphinx or lucene right for me? (prominence search and synonyms search)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, lucene, sphinx

I did a quick research on these search engines, but I have not found what I was looking for.

What interests me is to implement a **search for synonyms** (currently I randomly implemented using the simple full-text search of mysql), but above all I care to calculate, rather than the density of keywords, the **prominence of keywords**:

that is, **"as soon as they, the keywords, appear" in the text** of the mysql index...

can I do this with these search engines?

the language I will use is PHP

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by 'prominence'. Others might figure it out, but get the feeling you have a better chance of getting an answer if you explain it a bit more. Are you expecting the engine to automatically deduce new synonums when they first used?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of what you want?